# how to set value of text field in html from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm doing project in nodejs and html .can anybody help how to set value to text field in html from server.js. For example I've text field with id  'name' on index.html. i use res.body.name = 'nametest' .but its not working .please give me a simple example . Thank you friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a field from the server, you want to make it a preset value which you define when sending the HTML or you want to set it dynamically later on. The first option is easy, the second one a bit advanced.

Let's look at option 1. This is just a very basic example! Please don't use this in production.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><!-- your stuff here --></head>
  <body><input type="text" name="someVal" value="{{someVal}}"></body>
</html>
```

This might be your HTML. Just but a distinctive placeholder where you want your value to go. There might be better techniques out there to do this, but for the sake of simplicity I chose this way.

`server.js`

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('index.html', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end(err);
      return;
    }

    data = data.toString().replace(/\{\{someVal\}\}/, 'your value here');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data, 'utf8');
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

This server.js will open a HTTP server on port 8080. It will try to read `index.html` from the same directory. If it fails, it will send the error message to the client, else it will replace your placeholder in your HTML with your value and then send the modified content to the client.
If that's all you want to do, PHP might do a better job for you (but that's just my 2 cents :) )

Option 2 is a lot more elaborate. You would have to either use AJAJ ([Asynchronous Javascript and JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAJ)) which requires the client to know when to fetch the value or you could make use of websockets which enable the server to push a value to the client. For either of those there are a lot of tutorials out there which are a lot more detailed than anything I could put together for you here.
If you want to use those techniques, but are a bit unsure about their iomplementation, you might want to look at frameworks like Meteor and Socket.IO

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. But when i run this example the console shows the error :                                                                                   "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" server.js
c:\Users\ashik\WebstormProjects\placement\database\server.js:15               
  data.replace(/\{\{someVal\}\}/, 'your value here');
     ^

TypeError: data.replace is not a function
    at c:\Users\ashik\WebstormProjects\placement\database\server.js:15:6
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. `data` is an object, so you have to call `toString()` on it before calling `replace()`. I fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir.now its working...is there any way to get its value by id or name to a external js file where i can store i database???/

Comment: No problem. If I solved your question, please mark my response as answer so other people will know that your question has been solved.
Yes, of course you could store all those things in a database. You could have a look at database modules (like MySQL). Alternatively you could use a JSON file. Please don't store the values in a .js file. .js files are for code, not for data.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm doing a profile page. So i want to sett value of a field in html from js file . How can i set the value of html filed from js by calling it id or name.

Comment: Google is a programmer's best friend. Even I just googled this :) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a client-side thing from the server-side. They're absolutely different physical layers.

What you need is *AJAX* to request a resource from your Web app to your NodeJS server-side app, and set what you put in you response to the whole *text field*.

Maybe you'll need to take a look at [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com) to build a simple RESTful service to share resources between your client and server tiers.