# How to send some context from node server to html template without using any template engines

Tags: node.js, express

server.js

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  let context = {title:"api",message:"root"}
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html',context)
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    title{{title}}
    message{{message}}
  </body>
</html>
```

how can i send title and message to index.html which is assigned in contex variable.

i found a lot of way to do it using some template engines like jade,ejs,pug etc.. but i want it in pure html.

please have a look into my code....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404358/how-to-set-value-of-text-field-in-html-from-nodejs) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using template engines like jade,ejs, pug or client side libraries like angular, react.
You cannot interpolate the meaning of {{title}} in the html side.

Another approach is using javascript to fetch the details from server

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let url="http://localhost:8001/test";
        fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
        .then( (result) => {
            console.log('success:', result)
            let div=document.getElementById('test');
            div.innerHTML=`title: ${result.title}<br/>message: ${result.message}`;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    //res.sendFile(__dirname +"/views/test.html",);
    res.json({title:"api",message:"root"});
})

app.get('/render',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname +"/views/test.html");
})
```