# Putting the values of nodejs var in html

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to use nodejs to read the IP address and display on a html page, here is what I've done so far:

**app.js**

```
    const express =require('express')
const app = express();
var os = require( 'os' );
var path = require('path')
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'))
  })

var networkInterfaces = Object.values(os.networkInterfaces())
    .reduce((r,a)=>{
        r = r.concat(a)
        return r;
    }, [])
    .filter(({family, address}) => {
        return family.toLowerCase().indexOf('v4') >= 0 &&
            address !== '127.0.0.1'
    })
    .map(({address}) => address);
var ipAddresses = networkInterfaces.join(', ')
console.log(ipAddresses);


app.get('/DHCP',(req,res)=>{
   return  networkInterfaces[1];

});

app.listen(1000)
```

and the **index.html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="DHCP"  align="middle"> DHCP:</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to web dev world so I just don't get how can I do it !
thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to have any templating engine like ejs ,handlebars or pug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set value of text field in html from nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404358/how-to-set-value-of-text-field-in-html-from-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) (e.g. [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)), then call [res.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) with an html template modified according your template engine's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
<p id="DHCP" align="middle">{{DHCP:}}</p>
```

This works if you previously set your application to use HTML instead of any View Engine.